# how Scan part of page by ImageEn in delphi?

Tags: delphi, components, scanning

i need to scan part of page by ImageEn in delphi for faster scanning like window7 paint scanner dialog!

i want to open the twain dialog like paint

[image]

Comment: what is your question? you want to open the twain dialog like paint does?

Comment: What *exactly* are you having problems with in the process of scanning a part of a page by *ImageEn* in Delphi? What have you tried (show your code) and how did it work or did it not work? Please read [**Asking**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to learn what you can ask about and how to present your question.

Comment: Contact the vendor

Comment: yes i want to open the twain dialog like paint

Answer (score 0):

Just need to select other scanner by "AcquireSource"

```
if ImageEnView.io.SelectAcquireSource then
begin
  ImageEnView.io.Acquire;
  ImageEnView.Stretch;
end;
```

[image]